# Linux Global descriptor Table and Local Descriptor Table alignement

Tags: linux, kernel

I’ve read an article about the Global and Local Descriptor Table alignement problem.

How can I know if the Linux Kernel is taking into account this issue?

In other words: Does  Linux manage correctly GDT or LDT for a 64-bit architecture?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: GDT normally [stands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table) for "Global **Descriptor** Table", not for "Global *Data* Table". So, what **exact domain** you are talking about, and what **exact** "alignment"  **problem** do you mean?

Comment: The problem is linked on the validity of the descriptors and how Linux manage it. Do you know if a special code is dealing with this in Linux kernel ?

Comment: You expect everyone has read the same article as you and understand what do you mean. But this is not an actual case, and for me "The problem is linked on the validity of the descriptors" means very a little. Again, please state the problem in the question post, or, at the very least, provide a reference to the resource which states the problem.

Comment: Yes, you’re right. I should have put the link but I can’t manage to find it again. If I remember well, the problem is linked to: How does Linux manage the GDT/LDT limit in order to make it valid in terms of alignment? Is the Linux code enough robustness to manage an alignment issue ?